# Issue with clicking an element within iframe using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm using the code below to replicate the action shown below.
The script is able to select the field that has the text "operator maintenance" and click it using action chains, however, it only goes to the appropriate next page with the Employee ID field randomly.

```
ieOptions = webdriver.IeOptions()
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgechromium", True)
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgepath",'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe')
ieOptions.ignore_zoom_level = True
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\IEDriverServer.exe', options=ieOptions)

for key in parks:
    if PK == key:
        driver.get(parks[key][0])
        PW = parks[key][1]

# switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.frame('MWFApplicationFrame')
# Now continue with login process
UserName = driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName")
UserName.send_keys(ID)
PassWord = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Password")
PassWord.send_keys(PW)
login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Login")
login.click()
# switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
emp = driver.find_element(By.ID, "menu").click()
driver.switch_to.frame('MWFPopupMenuFrame')
hoverable = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "popupMenuCell")
ActionChains(driver)\
        .move_to_element(hoverable)\
        .click(hoverable)\
            .perform()
```

Manual flow:

[image]

Actual issue with script:

[image]

Html of webpage shown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the url of the page please

Comment: sure but in order to login you need to connected to company vpn, https://swcp2281/backoffice/framework/pages/

Answer (score 0):

As the desired element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.popupMenuFrame#MWFPopupMenuFrame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.popupMenuMainTable table.popupMenuSubTable tr[screenName='Operator Maintenance'] > td"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='popupMenuFrame' and @id='MWFPopupMenuFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='popupMenuMainTable']//table[@class='popupMenuSubTable']//tr[@screenName='Operator Maintenance']/td"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```